# Table field value to column (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I know, there are similar questions, but I can't understad it. I hope, you will help me to understand=)
I have a 3 tables:

1. Contact `(int ID, nvarchar Name)`
2. City `(int ID, nvarchar Name, int ContCount)`
3. Address `(int ID, int CityID, int ContactID, int Year)`

I need to make a table like this:

```
City | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 |
 LA  |  201 |  231 |  198 |  211 |
```

Where 2010-2013 - values from `Address.Year` and {201, 231, 198, 211} are from `City.ContCount`
Is in SQL some way to do it? If is, can you tell me about it=) I'll be really grateful)
I'm novice in SQL, so even simple questions are hard to me)

Comment: [Using pivot and unpivot in Sql Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a two dimensional array in Sql, which is tricky. I know it isn't quite what you are asking, but the simplest solution is to do this with a group by like so

```
SELECT Year, City, Count(*)
FROM Address a
JOIN City c ON a.CityID = c.CityID
GROUP BY Year, City
```

which will give you

```
City, Year, Count
LA, 2010, 201
LA, 2011, 231
...
```

This will allow you to pivot on this data (In excel for example) to get what you need.

There is also a pivot option in T-SQL explained [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)